# How to use a fixed size C array type in vala?

Tags: vala, vapi

Assume I have a C code (dcomplex.h):

```
typedef double dcomplex[2];
```

and want to use such a data type in vala. **What can be the minimal vapi file and vala call for it?**

(The ultimate goal is to use the C99 complex.h types.)

I tried many variants of the following dcomplex.vapi file:

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "dcomplex.h")]
namespace DComplex {
   [SimpleType]
   [CCode (cname = "dcomplex", has_type_id = false)]
   public struct DoubleComplex {
   }
}
```

and using in vala code like:

```
using DComplex;
void main()
{  
   DoubleComplex x = {1.0, 2.0};
   stdout.printf("x = %f + i %f\n", x[0], x[1]);
}
```

The compilation

```
valac --vapidir . --pkg dcomplex test.vala
```

leads to errors:

```
error: too many expressions in initializer list for `Complex.DoubleComplex'
DoubleComplex x = {1.0, 2.0};
                   ^^^

error: The expression `Complex.DoubleComplex' does not denote an array
stdout.printf("x = %f + i %f\n", x[0], x[1]);
                                 ^^^^
```

Comment: DoubleComplex x = {1.0, 2.0}; - may be this type:"DoubleComplex" is a structure, not array of 2 elements?

Comment: That's right observation, for sure. Such behaviour is somewhat expected. The question is what to use instead so that it anyhow works. The vala vapi doc also says `public struct Sth : double {}` for instance. But I cannot use it for arrays like `public struct DoubleComplex : double[2] {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `public struct DoubleComplex`: I don't think you can bind to a typedefed C array and expect Vala to be able to access its members or fields.
2. `DoubleComplex x = {1.0, 2.0};` is a initialization of arrays. You will not be able to use this initialization since we cannot let Vala knows its type is an binded "opaque" array.

I understand you want to use C99 complex features, so, bellow, I present my solution to bind to `complex.h`. To make the complex header more Vala fiendly, I'd not write and VAPI to bind it directly, instead I'd write a C wrapper object based style typedefing `double complex` to something Vala can bind to.

First I'll show the wrapper, it is composed of three files:

- `Complex.h` for the prototypes, typedef and inclusion of `<complex.h>`;
- `Complex.c` for the implementation of wrapper functions and;
- `Complex.vapi` to bind in Vala.

file `Complex.h`

```
#include <complex.h>

typedef double complex dcomplex;

void dcomplex_make (dcomplex * c, double r, double i);

double dcomplex_real (dcomplex * c);
double dcomplex_imag (dcomplex * c);
```

file `Complex.c`

```
#include "Complex.h"

void dcomplex_make (dcomplex * c, double r, double i)
{
    *c = CMPLX(r, i);
}

double dcomplex_real (dcomplex * c)
{
    return creal(*c);
}

double dcomplex_imag (dcomplex * c)
{
    return cimag(*c);
}
```

file `Complex.vapi`

```
[CCode (cheader_filename = "Complex.h")]
namespace Complex
{
    [CCode (cname = "dcomplex")]
    public struct DComplex {
        [CCode (cname = "dcomplex_make")]
        public DComplex (double real, double imaginary);

        [CCode (cname = "dcomplex_real")]
        public double real ();

        [CCode (cname = "dcomplex_imag")]
        public double imag ();
    }
}
```

Now that you have the wrapper and VAPI, you can use it in Vala code:

file `Main.vala`

```
using Complex;

class Main {
    static void main() {
        DComplex c = DComplex(10, 20);

        stdout.printf("C Complex Type = %f %f\n", c.real(), c.imag());
    }
}
```

To build and run:

```
# valac Main.vala Complex.vapi Complex.c
# ./Main
```

The presented example outputs:

```
C Complex Type = 10.000000 20.000000
```